# select multiple rows form a table and insert into a different table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select, sql-insert

I have the following tables..

Passengers:

```
| Reservation_number | Passport_number | Full_name |
|--------------------|-----------------|-----------|
| 1                  | 1               | abc       |
| 1                  | 2               | def       |
| 1                  | 3               | ghi       |
```

Booking:

```
| Booking_id | Reservation_number | Card_number | Price |
|------------|--------------------|-------------|-------|
| 1          | 1                  | 6767        | 460   |
```

Ticket:

```
| Booking_id | Passport_number | Ticket_number |
|------------|-----------------|---------------|
|            |                 |               |
|            |                 |               |
```

From Passengers,i want to select all the Passport_number's for which Reservation_number is 1(here it is all the 3 rows) and then insert each of those Passport_number's into each row of Ticket table. After that, all the rows for Booking_id in Ticket table must be set to 1 since the Booking_id is 1 for Reservation_number=1(this can be seen in Booking table). How can i do it?

Comment: I don't know much about the above scenario. But I suggest you use one table to store passengers and ticket tables. Every passenger has only a passport number and ticket number. I think using two tables for that is meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the `insert ... select` syntax.

You can join `booking` and `passengers`, and `insert` the resultset into `ticket` as follows:

```
insert into ticket(booking_id, passport_number, ticket_number)
select b.booking_id, b.reservation_number, p.passport_number
from booking b
inner join passengers p on p.reservation_number = b.reservation_number
```